# Convert output into key=value pair

Tags: bash

I have a script (I don't have edit access) which output whether the server is up or not. Essentially outputting either `true` or `false`.

How can I convert that output from lets say true to a key value pair like `server_up=true` or `server_up=false`. I tried using `awk '{print $0}` but didn't get very far. Not really sure how I can prepend string before it.

Thanks for any insights team!

Comment: Do it output only `true` or `false`?

Comment: Yes - that's all it outputs :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the output is *only* `true` or `false`, for one server, you can assign it directly to a variable.

```
server_up=$( prog.sh some arg list )
```

If you need that as a k=v pair,

```
printf "server_up=%s\n" $( prog.sh some arg list )
```

Obviously you have to run the program itself to get the output, but there's no need for an `awk`.

If you just *want* to use `awk`,

```
prog.sh your args | awk '{ print "server_up="$0 }'
```

or `sed`,

```
prog.sh your args | sed 's/^/server_up=/'
```

if there might be spaces to clean up, then

```
prog.sh your args | sed 's/^ */server_up=/'
```

or

```
prog.sh your args | sed -E 's/^\s*(\S+)\s*$/server_up=\1/'
```

Comment: As always, there are more ways to skin ze cat! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using the builtin `read` command with [ProcSub](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -r value < <(script_that_generates_the_output)

server_up=$value
```

---

To answer this:

> How can I convert that output from lets say true to a key value pair like server_up=true or server_up=false.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -r value < <(script_that_generates_the_output)

case "$value" in
  true) server_up=true;;
  false) server_up=false;;
esac
```

The `case` statement is most probably superfluous though.

Answer (score 0):

Just output the variable with `=` in front of it then.

```
printf server_up=
prog.sh your args
```